# How to get result from SQL select query with Slick 3

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I want to run a custom sql select request to my DB. Following the slick 3 [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html) I ended up with something like this

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.1",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35",

import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

val db = Database.forURL(url, username, password, driver = driver)

val s = sql"""select name, email from users""".as[(String, String)]

val f: Future[Unit] = db.run(DBIO.seq(s))
```

But I want to get a Seq of Tuples. How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `DBIO` [documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIO$):

> def seq[E <: Effect](actions: DBIOAction[_, NoStream, E]*):
>   DBIOAction[Unit, NoStream, E]
>
> A simpler version of sequence that takes a number of DBIOActions with
>   any return type as varargs and returns a DBIOAction that performs the
>   individual actions in sequence (using andThen), returning () in the
>   end.

So, `DBIO.seq` will always return `Unit`. If you just want to execute a single query, just pass the query itself to the `db.run` method. Thus, you last line would be:

`val f: Future[Seq[(String, String)] = db.run(s)`